# Reorder column level for Pandas Unstack

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataset

[image]

When I use `dataframe.unstack()` it produces this result

[image]

How can I reverse the column levels.
Desired output:

```
Level 0: Cat1
-> Level 1: count
-> Level 1: amount

Level 0: Cat2
-> Level 1: count
-> Level 1: amount
```

Comment: use `df.swaplevel` : `dataframe.unstack().swaplevel(axis=1)` ?

Comment: Does not produce the desired output unfortunately:
cat1   | cat2   | cat 1     | cat2
count | count | amount | amount

Comment: `dataframe.unstack().swaplevel(0, 1, 1).sort_index(1)` ?